# What are the solutions to implementing the fault-injection in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, aspectj, fault

In practice, what are the possible ways to implement the fault injection in hadoop. And what are their cons and pros?

Currently our candidate solution is AspectJ. But how it feels to implement fault injection in Hadoop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop actually has a fault injection framework. See [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/faultinject_framework.html).